# I want to use scatter with scrollview in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview, scatter-plot, kivymd

I have this code in a.kv file

file .kv

`

```
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: False

    GridLayout:
        spacing: 10
        padding: 1
        cols: 1
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.minimum_size

        
        Image:
            size_hint: None, None
            size:root.width * 1 , root.height * 2
            source: "learn1.jpg"
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False

        Image:
            size_hint: None, None
            size:root.width * 1 , root.height * 2
            source: "learn2.jpg"
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False

        Image:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: root.width * 1, root.height * 2
            source: "learn3.jpg"
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False`
```

I want to use Scatter so that I can zoom in and out of images with two fingers

So that when I want to zoom in and out of the pictures with two fingers, the pictures make them zoom in and out, is this possible?
And also I will do it myself but it was not happening I find the images still do not get smaller or bigger and I also find that scrollview has been disabled So I want to add a scatter with scrollview without disabling scrolview